# When were finite fields introduced and when were they first called Galois fields?

Tags: finite-fields, math-history

W. H. Bussey (1905) "Galois field tables for $p^n \le 169$", *Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society* 12(1): 22–38, `doi:10.1090/S0002-9904-1905-01284-2`

- When were finite fields introduced?
- And why?
- When were they first called Galois fields?
- Is the name *Galois field* justified?

Comment: This would be more appropriate on the History of Science and Math SE, wouldn't it?

Comment: And the question "When were finite fields introduced?" is more concrete asking when were they called "finite fields", because otherwise the use of the object itself you will trace it back, without the name, into [the history of modular arithmetic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086008000670).

Comment: Finite fields of prime power order were in effect used in Galois's 1830 paper *Sur la theorie des nombres*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Galois introduced finite fields in this paper:

Galois, Évariste (1830). "Sur la théorie des nombres". Bulletin des Sciences mathématiques. XIII: 428.

So says Wikipedia, and also Dickson in his 1900 book on the topic.

EDIT: There's more information in Lidl and Niederreiter, Finite Fields (Volume 20 in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics series). For the Galois paper, they give the following bibliographical information:

Bull. Sci. Math. de M. Férussac 13 (1830) 428-435; J. Math. Pures Appl. 11 (1846) 398-407; Oeuvres math., pp. 15-23, Gauthier-Villars, Paris, 1897.

They also say, "Rudiments of the theory are also contained in a posthumous manuscript of Gauss" Analysis residuorum: Caput octavum. Disquisitiones generales de congruentiis, Werke, vol. 2, pp. 212-240, Konigl. Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften, Gottingen, 1876; Untersuchungen uber Hohere Arithmetik (H. Maser, ed.), pp. 630-652, Springer, Berlin, 1889.

And they say see Niederreiter, Richard Dedekind and the development of the theory of finite fields, Abh. Braunschweig. Wissenschaftl. Gesellschaft 33 (1982) 183-187, for a discussion of the early history of the subject.